# Binary search tree - iterative insert method leaves tree empty

Tags: javascript, loops, binary-search-tree

I tried to create the `insert` method for a binary search tree, but 'this.root' remains `null`.

My logic is:

As long as `current` (which at the beginning is `this.root`) is not `null`, continue to update the `current` variable, by comparing it with the value we want to insert (if it's greater or less).
When `current` is `null`, we assign it the new Node:

```
class Node {
    constructor(value){
        this.value = value
        this.left = null
        this.right = null
    }
}

class BST {
    constructor(){
        this.root = null
        this.count = 0
    }

    insert(value){
        this.count++
        let current = this.root;
        while(current){
            if(value<current){
                current=current.left
            }
            if(value>current){
                current=current.right
            }
        }
        current = new Node(value);
    }    
}

let Binst = new BST(10);
Binst.insert(22)
Binst.insert(12)
Binst.insert(4)
console.log(Binst)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are these issues:

- Comparing `value` with `current` is not right: that is comparing a number with an object. You need to compare with `current.value`
- In the main program you call the `BST` constructor with an argument, but the constructor does not expect an argument. Although you could adapt the constructor to take that argument, it is better to *not* pass an argument to the constructor and have an extra call of `insert` in your main program.
- `current = new Node(value)` will not change the tree. It only assigns a new node to a local variable. In order to extend the tree, you need to assign the new node to a `left` or `right` property of an existing node (or to the `root` property of the BST instance). Assigning to a *variable* **never** mutates your object structure.
- `this.root` is never assigned anything else after its initialisation with `null`. Again, assigning to `current`, is never going to change `this.root`.
- Because of the previous points, you need to stop your loop one iteration earlier -- when `current` points to the node that is about to get a new child.  And you also need to deal separately with the case where the new node must become the root of the tree.

The following are just suggestions, not problems:

- It is better practice to separate your statements with semicolons. There is the [automatic semicolon insertion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846283/what-are-the-rules-for-javascripts-automatic-semicolon-insertion-asi) algorithm, but you wouldn't be the first to fall in one if its traps. Better take control over it yourself.
- It is common practice to name variables with an initial capital when they are classes (constructors), but for *instances* a lower case initial letter is commonly used. So `binst` or `bIntst` instead of `Binst`. I would even suggest a more readable name, like `tree`.

Here is the corrected code:

```js
class Node {
    constructor(value) {
        this.value = value;
        this.left = null;
        this.right = null;
    }
}

class BST {
    constructor() {
        this.root = null;
        this.count = 0;
    }

    insert(value) {
        this.count++;
        let current = this.root;
        if (!current) {
            this.root = new Node(value);
            return;
        }
        while (true) {
            if (value < current.value){
                if (current.left) {
                    current = current.left;
                } else {
                    current.left = new Node(value);
                    return;
                }
            }
            if (value > current.value) {
                if (current.right) {
                    current = current.right;
                } else {
                    current.right = new Node(value);
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

let tree = new BST();
tree.insert(10);
tree.insert(22);
tree.insert(12);
tree.insert(4);
console.log(tree);
```